# Does halacha permit wife-beating?

Tags: halacha, rambam

Some have claimed that Maimonides wrote that it is ok to beat your wife. They point to this verse [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952895/jewish/Ishut-Chapter-Twenty-One.htm). Does the halacha "allow" wife-beating and does the Rambam really permits this?

Comment: See footnote 16 on that page.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.154.3

Comment: Which law are you reffering to?

Comment: "We compel" is always in the plural there, *kofin*. That's the court system's job, not the husband's. There's an earlier place in the chapter where Chabad mistakenly translated *ain kofin* as "he may not compel" rather than *we may not compel.* (Singular would be *aino kofeh*.)

Comment: @Shalom Thank you. I agree with you.